# HTML - Disabling a widget in one of my pages

Tags: php, html, django, if-statement

I need to disable a widget for some of my pages, How can i do it?

A hard try that i thought will be to somehow put a condition in the html (django or php?) of the widget 
that if the site URL != the URL i don't want.  it will appear.

How can i do it?
Any other different method?

the widget code is:

```
    <div class="{%- if settings.cart_position == 'side' -%}jas-mini-cart jas-push-menu{%-else-%}dropdown-cart{%-endif-%}">
   {%- if settings.cart_position == 'side' -%}
      <h3 class="mg__0 tc cw bgb tu ls__">{{ 'cart.widget.title' | t }}<i class="close-cart pe-7s-close pa"></i></h3>
   {%- endif -%}
      <div class="widget_shopping_cart pr">
         <div class="widget_shopping_cart_content">
            {%- include 'cart_body' -%}
         </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First Get the current page URL using Php and then compare it with the URL which you want to compare.

**How to get the current page URL:**

https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-get-current-page-url-in-php

After getting the current page URL, then compare it using an IF statement and then display your Widget code.